# How to access WSL files from Windows 11 task scheduler script

Tags: windows, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scheduled-tasks, wsl2

In .BAT file running from Task Scheduler task as administator user

eriting to file Windows Subsystem for Linux drive using

```
echo test >\\wsl.localhost\Debian\var\lib\postgresql\12\test
```

throws error

> The network name cannot be found.

If this command is issued from command line, it works.

How to access WSL files from Task Scheduler Script file ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to run a batch file that uses the batch `mkdir`
command to create a folder on the host, although inside the Debian
distribution's folder. So why do it through batch?

It would simpler to do something like (untested) :

```
wsl -d Debian -e 'mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/12/20221204'
```

Or

```
wsl -d Debian -- mkdir /var/lib/postgresql/12/20221204
```

Comment: Real script uses pg_basebackup to write to Debian disk. How to write data to Debian disk from bat file running from Task Scheduler?

Comment: @harrymc just ***showed you the exact answer to your question***.  Use THAT COMMAND instead of yours.  This answer shows you how to run the command within the context of the bash shell (FROM BATCH) instead of trying to go between windows and Linux boundaries.

Comment: I updated question and changed example to more real. Real question is like question title is ´How to access WSL files from Task Sheduler script´

Comment: Same answer also for the updated question. There's no difference between `mkdir` and `echo` - the same method still applies. Why do you insist on using Windows apps to operate on Linux files?

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler runs pg_basebackup. It should create database directory in Linux file system to be used by Linux application.

Comment: PostgreSQL is also available on Windows. Why do you need WSL?

Comment: Master server is running in Debian. Cross platform binary replication is not supported in Postgres due to binary locale representation differences in Windows and Linux. Queries return incorrect results. WSL is used to provide hot standby of Debian master server.